# How to update a single graph in chart from multiple async threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, graph, charts

```
 Parallel.foreach(list<> , a=>  
    {  
    // do some operation  
         chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);  
    });
```

I want to draw different lines for each thread invoked in parallel. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through the dispatcher associated to the control:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, a=>  
{
    // do some operation 
    chart1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y); }));
});
```

Comment: But in this you are writing to the same series index....it will draw the same line for all the threads then right?